# how to add a link button in the grid view by visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I want to add a link button in grid view that will navigate to the next form in the website. but i want to know how to insert that button into the grid view column? please help me..

Comment: How about using `TemplateColumns` ?

Comment: Simply add the link button in the IteTemplate of grid view, if you not able to do it in design view use source view of visual studio.

Comment: i am trying to edit by template but i am not able to redirect to next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Link buttons in the Item template of a gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Link" runat="server" PostBackUrl="MyNextPage.aspx">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: when i am using this code then it is showing a error. that is control error. can u tell me how to use it by designing.

Comment: Tell me the error, if it is giving a specific error. This code individually shouldn't give an error.

Comment: This code needs to be inside gridview tag, in columns tag. See this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton5_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

```
<Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
              <HeaderTemplate>
                   // TEXT FOR COLUMN NAME
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                    // ADD LINK BUTTON HERE.   
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

Add this inside grid view.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Link" HeaderText="LinkButton"/>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your GridViews datasource is bound. Set Auto-Generate Columns to false.
Open GridViewTask , add new column with Hyperlink Field proper name and path . You are done.

Comment: but by hyperlink i can not make any event. so i need to use the link button.

Comment: Then add a TemplateField in the GridView using the EditColumn option from the context menu when you click on the smart tag.

-> Add a TemplateField in the Selected Fields list.
 
-> Now Right click on the Grid and select Edit Templates. Now drop the link control in the ItemTemplate of the Grid.

-> Now bind the property of the link column field in the table using Data Bindings.

-> Now if you click on the hyperlink, it will take you to that page.

Comment: First thing first, tell us exactly what you want to do when you click the Link button. You want to show another page or what ???? Look, We are here to help you only, but please be specific.